# volume boost AudioKit

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audiokit

> This is related to [GitHub](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/) AudioKit!

I was wondering if there is a method to increase the volume of local stored AudioFiles **above the default volume (1.0)**

**Have a look at some example code:**

```
let metronome = AKSamplerMetronome()
let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "filename", withExtension: "wav")

metronome.sound = file
metronome.volume = 1.0 // How to volume boost on local file called "filename.wav"?
metronome.play()
```

Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes. There are several standard AudioKit DSP components that can increase the volume.

For example, you can use a simple method like `AKBooster`:
http://audiokit.io/docs/Classes/AKBooster.html

Plus, there are several additional methods you can use to dynamically manipulate the volume of your signal chain. These include compressors, limiters, and more: 
http://audiokit.io/docs/Dynamics%20Nodes.html

Comment: links don't work anymore.